# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement request (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for request

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, visual-studio-code, request

I am unable to use the request module from flask library in my visual studio code

```
from model import manual_testing
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask,request, render_template, jsonify
import requests
import pickle


app = Flask(__name__)
model = pickle.load(open('C:\\Users\\hp\\flask1\\env\\model.pkl', 'rb'))

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/predict_api',methods=['POST'])
def predict_api():
    '''
    For direct API calls trought request
    '''
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    prediction = model.predict([np.array(list(data.values()))])

    output = prediction[0]
    return jsonify(output)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am not able to import the request module in my flask program
python version 3.7

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Your title suggests that you are not able to install some package (`requests`?). There should be no problem to install `requests` via `pip`. Show what have you tried. Also, note that the title suggests you try to install `request`, not `requests`. Probably it is just a typo  - check your `pip` command. Note the package name.

Comment: Also note that in your code you import requests, but never use it. Do you really need [to install and import] `requests`?

Comment: when i tried to import module called request I got this error .What should i do

Comment: This message _Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement request (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for request_ will be displayed when you try to install `request` with `pip`. What I ask is WHY you try to install `request` - there is NO such package. You import `request` from `flask` (i.e. you will need to `pip install flask` and also you try to import `requests` which you never use but nevertheless will be installed `pip install requests`.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error today and I found a solution.

pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org requests

It works with Python 3.10 and Pip 23.
It doesn't work with Python 3.11.  The error message is "Requirement already satisfied"